# Missing Websphere NodeAgent JMX MBean

Tags: java, websphere, jmx

I am trying to run the sample code from IBM ([sample code link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tjmx_customjava_jsr160.html)) to connect to Websphere Application Server v7.0 through a JMX client.

I could successfully connect to the Websphere MBeanServer by jconsole, and could see two domains exist (JMImplementation and WebSphere). However, I found that there is no NodeAgent MBean as specified in the sample code with ObjectName pattern `WebSphere:type=NodeAgent,node=<some node>,*`.

Does anybody know why the NodeAgent MBean is not there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which edition of WebSphere are you running?  WebSphere Express does not include node agents or a deployment manager.  WebSphere Network Deployment includes these components to support a variety of features.  It's filled with marketing speak, but IBM has a [PDF](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/7938_IBM_WebSphere_Application_Data_Sheet_WSD14089-USEN-01_Specifications.pdf) listing high-level differences between the various editions.

Comment: There are three key constructs in a WAS Server. Deployment Manager, Node Agent and an Application Server. Depending on the product you have bought and the way your have configured them, you might or might not have access to various components (eg Dmgr or Node Agent). What is it that the sample code tries to do and what do you want to achieve. Perhaps providing information on that would help us in helping you.

Comment: I run the WAS server in my RAD environment and it seems that only the Application Server is running.

Answer (score 2):

You can run such query "WebSphere:*" - so you will get all mbeans you have in time of query evaluated. Just print it out to get expression what you actually have. For example i have only server and portal mbeans in my configuration and no nodeAgent. So this sample will not work in my environment too.